# How to upload images programmatically into a media picker in umbraco 7 back office content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

Can anybody help me to upload an image programmatically into a media picker in Umbraco 7 back office content page.

I have added the user submitted images into the media library. Also I can upload the images to an "upload" property type in the same content page. But as I am a newbie with Umbraco. I dont know how to add images to media picker. I am following MVC format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it after some trial and runs. It was so simple. 
Just assign the created media Id into the corresponding property value of page.
Like following:

```
    doc.getProperty("image").Value = media.Id;
```

And if you need to add more than one items then:

Iterate each media IDs and make a comma separated string

```
    imgIdList = imgIdList + "," + medid.Id;
```

then assign the  comma separated string to the property value.

```
    doc.getProperty("image").Value = imgIdList;
```

Hopes it will help somebody who are having the same problem